# Limit input into Gtk.Entry to numbers only

Tags: gtk4, gtkentry

I am using GTK 4 with Python and have a [`Gtk.Entry`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Entry.html) widget which I would like to limit the characters which can be entered to numbers only. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could connect the `changed` signal of teh `Gtk.Entry` to a callback function. In the call back function check the content of the input and remove ny non-numeric chars

```py
def on_entry_changed(self, entry):
    # Use GLib.idle_add to delay the action until the main loop is idle
    GLib.idle_add(filter_entry_text, entry)

def filter_entry_text(entry):
    text = entry.get_text()
    new_text = ''.join([char for char in text if char.isdigit()])
    if new_text != text:
        entry.set_text(new_text)
        entry.set_position(-1)
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works, but I get warnings that "Cannot begin irreversible action while in user action", and it also moves the cursor to the beginning.

Comment: I updated the snipped so the cursor is on put on the end, and also I'm using GLib so that the text is added to the entry when the main loop is iddle. This would prevent the warnings.

Comment: Moving the cursor to the end is not ideal since it makes it difficult to edit text in between numbers. But perhaps Gtk is shitty and your answer is "good enough".